# how to get started or know techonlogy they use for shazam or intonow?

Tags: design-patterns, architecture

Its really amazing to see technology like shazam and IntoNow(has been acquired by Yahoo!).

I wanted to know how they develop such a product? 
what technology they use? 
what architecture they follow for building?
how they build the audio tracing technology? where with a slice of audio they trace a million or more records and get the details
Is there any sites or books where i can learn those?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Shazam, you might find these two links interesting:

- http://laplacian.wordpress.com/2009/01/10/how-shazam-works/
- http://www.ee.columbia.edu/~dpwe/papers/Wang03-shazam.pdf (paper of the shazam inventor)